# Dependency injection benefits - Testing with mock data?

Tags: dependency-injection

I readout the benefits of the dependency injection, 
one thing I can't understand is

"with DI testing can be done easily with mock data"

Unable to get clear picture how to test with mock data?

How testing can be done?

Can anyone explain with simple example?

Comment: Take a look at this very interesting Google Talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0

Answer (score 0):

when you have this class constructor:

```
Client(Service service) {
 this.service = service;

}
```

you use DI to decouple your objects dependency(in this case Client have a Service strong dependency), so you apply a basic form of DI:

```
Client(IService service){
 this.service = service;

}
```

where service is now every object which implements IService interface
When you test this class, you can easily instrument this service dependency by mock objects:

```
private MockRepository _mocks;


    [SetUp]
    public void initialize()
    {
        _mocks = new MockRepository();            
    }

    [Test]
    public void should_be_able_to_get_the_right_work() 
    {
        var myMockedservice = _mocks.DynamicMock<IService>();

        var client= new Client(myMockedservice);

        // some work      
    }
```

Try this nice article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30381/Introduction-to-Mocking)